# PHP string to timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, time, timestamp

i would like to change my french date **Jeudi, 22 Août 2013** to timestamp.

i've tried thing like this but it didin't work

```
ladate = new Date("F j, Y...","Jeudi, 22 Août 2013");
echo $ladate;
```

Comment: @Gavin can you be more specific, thanks ^^

Comment: its strtotime(), http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: @Jack i have nothing XD, i just wanna change my french date 'Jeudi, 22 Août 2013' to timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`strptime()`](http://php.net/strptime) to work with localized date formats; it returns an array of information that you can use with [`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime) to create a timestamp:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');

$date = 'Jeudi, 22 Août 2013';

$a = strptime($date, '%A, %d %B %Y');
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon']+1, $a['tm_mday'], $a['tm_year'] + 1900);
// int(1377129600)
```

However, it's not implemented in Windows; you may need to resort to the [intl extension](http://php.net/intl) or replace day and month names into English :)